# Error when running Heckit Test for sample selection correction in R

Tags: r

I want to run `heckit` to correct my results for sample selection bias.  This is my code:

```
ht <- heckit(participation ~ log(friends+2) +log(followers+2) + subjectivity.bnk, delta_polarity ~ subjectivity.bnk , df))
```

my IV is `subjectivity.bnk` and my DV is `delta_polarity`. I have `friends` and `followers` as my heckman instruments. When I run the code, I get the following eror:

```
Error in binaryChoice(formula, ..., userLogLik = loglik, weights = weights) : 
  the left hand side of the 'formula' has to contain exactly two levels (e.g. FALSE and TRUE)
```

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1POIBgEnh2ZX8k9DtIISGj7UUv7veFCUEu2QKVUDq3fQ) is a sample of my data.

Thanks

Comment: `library(sampleSelection)`

Comment: We can only speculate without seeing a sample of your data. Please use `dput(head(df))` or literal `data.frame(...)` to provide an unambiguous representation of your data.

Comment: @r2evans I added a link to a sample of my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observations (rows) that have 1 for participation, also have NA for subjectivity.bnk. So when you include subjectivity.bnk in the first part, you end up with only 0s for partcipation:

```
library(sampleSelection)
df = read.delim("ht.csv - ht.csv.tsv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#participation is good
table(df$participation)
 0   1 
117 382 
# see that those with NA for subjectivity.bnk also have 1 for participation
table(df$participation,is.na(df$subjectivity.bnk))

    FALSE TRUE
  0     0  117
  1   382    0

#this works
ht <- heckit(participation ~ log(friends+2) +
log(followers+2), delta_polarity ~ subjectivity.bnk , df)
```